# React How to set scroll point onScroll event

Tags: reactjs

I need to store scroll position on state. I am doing that in the following way. But don't know how it's not scrolling the div.

```
const [scroll, setScroll] = (0)
const scrollRef = useRef(null);

 const onScroll = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setScroll(myRef.current.scrollLeft);
  };

   <div   ref={myRef} onScroll={onScroll}
        >
         <h5>item 1 </h5>
         <h5>item 2 </h5>
         <h5>item 3 </h5>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `e.preventDefault`. This means that the default behaviour is prevented. In this case, the scroll.
Remove that line and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used

```
componentDidMount() {
    let left_scroll = document.querySelector('.className')
    left_scroll.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
   }


handleScroll = (e) => {
    let left_scroll = document.querySelector('.className') 
    if (left_scroll.scrollTop == 0){
        document.getElementById('button_className').classList.remove("hidden")
      }else if(left_scroll.scrollHeight > 800 && left_scroll.scrollTop >= 700){
        document.getElementById('button_className').classList.add("hidden") 
      }
  }
```

what I have done here is, get that div and I have tried to show and hide a button as per page scroll heigh